# Prove that for any sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $A×(B\setminus C) = (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is Velleman's exercise 4.1.8 ("$×$" means the Cartesian product):

Prove that for any sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $A×(B\setminus C) = (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.

Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A × B$ is equal to $\{(a, b) | a ∈ A and b ∈ B\}$ ("$(a, b)$" is an ordered pair).

And here's my proof of it:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $A×(B\setminus C)$, then $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$ which means that $y ∈ B$ and $y ∉ C$. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ B$, we get $(x, y) ∈ (A×B)$. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∉ C$, we get $(x, y) ∉ (A×C)$. Thus $(x, y) ∈ (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$. Therefore $A×(B\setminus C) ⊆ (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.

($\leftarrow$) Let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $(A×B)\setminus (A×C)$, then $(x, y) ∈ (A×B)$ which means that $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ B$ and $(x, y) ∉ (A×C)$ which means that either $x$ is not an element of $A$ or $y$ is not an element of $C$ or both. But since we saw that $x ∈ A$, therefore $y ∉ C$. From $y ∈ B$ and $y ∉ C$, we get $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$, we get $(x, y) ∈ A×(B\setminus C)$. Therefore $(A×B)\setminus (A×C) ⊆ A×(B\setminus C)$.

From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$), we get $A×(B\setminus C) = (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.

Is my proof correct (particularly "From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∉ C$, we get $(x, y) ∉ (A×C)$" in the forward direction)?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: I would call it $\subseteq,\supseteq$ instead of $\rightarrow,\leftarrow$, since $=$ is about sets that contain one another, not logical statements that imply one another, but it's not terribly important. If you make the simple rewrite $A×(B\setminus C) = (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$ into $x\in A×(B\setminus C) \iff x\in (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$, then arrows is more correct again. And it doesn't affect the actual proof.

Comment: Re the "particularly" part: you don't need x member of A for that statement. If y not member of C than (x, y) not member of S x C for any set S and any value x member S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ($\rightarrow$) Let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $A×(B\setminus C)$, then $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$ which means that $y ∈ B$ and $y ∉ C$. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ B$, we get <s>`$(x, y) ∈ (A×B)$`</s> $(x,y)\in A\times B$. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∉ C$, we get $(x, y) ∉ (A×C)$. `(Enough to say "From y ∉ C, ...")` Thus $(x, y) ∈ (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$. Therefore $A×(B\setminus C) ⊆ (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.
>
> ($\leftarrow$) Let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $(A×B)\setminus (A×C)$, then $(x, y) ∈ (A×B)$ `(Redundant parentheses)` which means that $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ B$ and $(x, y) ∉ (A×C)$ `(Redundant parentheses)` which means that either $x$ is not an element of $A$ or $y$ is not an element of $C$ or both. But since we saw that $x ∈ A$, therefore $y ∉ C$. From $y ∈ B$ and $y ∉ C$, we get $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$ `(Redundant parentheses)`. From $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ (B\setminus C)$, we get $(x, y) ∈ A×(B\setminus C)$. Therefore $(A×B)\setminus (A×C) ⊆ A×(B\setminus C)$.
>
> From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$), we get $A×(B\setminus C) = (A×B)\setminus (A×C)$.

`(Just several redundant parentheses for sets. Your proof is correct.)`